# In Backbone.js how do i call a function in one view from another view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, openlayers, backbone-views

I have my views seperated into separate files.  In my main view I am trying to call a function in another view.  Is there a way to do this in Backbone.js?

Comment: You might trigger a custom event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way would be to use the Mediator pattern so you do not tightly couple your views.
In the latest versions of Backbone, the `Backbone` object can be used as a mediator.

In view 1: `Backbone.trigger('somethingHappened', {id: 1});`

In view 2:

```
//action when 'something' happens
onSomething : function(data){
    console.log('Got that: ' + data.id)
}
//... in the view init ...
Backbone.on('somethingHappened', onSomething)
//... in the view destruction...
Backbone.off('somethingHappened', onSomething);
```

You may also use the more recent `listenTo` method.
Of course it will only work if view2 has been initialized.

Comment: In my View 1: I have a function and in that function is this call.  'Backbone.trigger('addMarkers', json);'   Then I have view 2.  and in the initialization i have 'Backbone.on('addMarkers', addMarkers);' and i have 'addMarkers: function(json){//....do something}'.  this doesn't seem to be working

Comment: add a console.log inside your addMarkers function to check it goes there. Are you also sure view2 has been initialized when view1 triggers 'addMarkers' ?